# Bareos: concurrent backup tasks of different priority?

Tags: backup, bacula, bareos

I am running Bareos 17.2.4 (latest free release). The default configuration will schedule a full backup of all clients on the first Saturday each month, and incremental backups from Monday to Friday.

Unfortunately I have so many clients that the full backup started at Saturday is not completed until next Thursday which means that Bareos schedules incremental backups but they pile up and don't run until after Thursday. So I don't have incremental backups for several days in a month.

Is there a way to give incremental backups a higher priority, so that they will execute before other full backups? 
Or is it possible to run two concurrent queues at the same time, one for the full backup and the other for the incremental backups?

Answer (score 1):

Bareos is capable of running backups simultaneously.  To do so all you need to do is add:

```
Maximum Concurrent Jobs = X
```

in the Director's configuration file(s) in the Director, Job, Client, and Storage resources.

However, enabling them in Job and Client as well allows them to be duplicated (so the same Client could be asked to perform 2 backups at the same time).

For the common use-case (1 backup server, multiple clients) it has been mentioned that this needs to be specifically in:

- Storage stanza in bareos-sd.conf (or bareos-sd.d/storage/bareos-sd.conf)
- Device stanza in bareos-sd.conf (or bareos-sd.d/device/*.conf
- Storage stanza in bareos-dir.conf (or bareos-dir.d/storage/*.conf)
- Director stanza in bareos-dir.conf (or bareos-dir.d/director/bareos-dir.conf)

Comment: I am already using the "Maximum Concurrent Jobs" setting, Bareos runs several backup clients in parallel, but the problem is that all backup jobs seem to have the same priority. So, when new incremental backups are scheduled, they will be processed only after all previous full backups are completed - which takes several days.

Comment: @nn4l Yes, this means that you are missing MCJ stanzas in Job or Client.